# How to say these words in academic writing?

Tags: academic-writing

1. grab attention
2. the talk of the town
3. fly in the ointment

How to transfer these words in an academic way?

Comment: grab attention = *stand out, be noticeable;* the talk of the town = *hot topic, talking point*; fly in the ointment = *drawback, pitfall.*

Comment: Depending on the type of academic content it not even be appropriate to incorporate the ideas represented by those words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has to be more ways to achieve that aim than those found below, but those seem to be satisfactory.

1. *catch/attract your/the interlocutor's attention/attentiveness*

[ref. 1, Italian Discourse: A Cultural Semantic Analysis](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Italian_Discourse/fZq1DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the+interlocutor%27s+attention%22&pg=PA136&printsec=frontcover) ... asks the interlocutor if he/she knows, the speaker obviously knows that this person does not know and takes advantage of this to catch the interlocutor's attention and curiosity,

2. *the talk of everybody in town*

([ref. 2, Parliamentary Debates (Hansard).: House of Commons official](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Parliamentary_Debates_Hansard/vFoeAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22the+talk+of+everybody%22&dq=%22the+talk+of+everybody%22&printsec=frontcover))  took the point of view that he did , but it The service given by Scottish Airways political pressure to bear in order to inseems to me that he was indeed bringing before the war was such that it was the talk of everybody

3. *what spoils it*

([ref. 3, The Spectator- Volumes 282-283](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Spectator/74LhAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22what+spoils+it%22&dq=%22what+spoils+it%22&printsec=frontcover)) What spoils it , writes Mr Grahame Hoyte of Southam , Warwickshire , ' is the sloppy spacing of sentences , merely because the printers will not leave the equivalent of two spaces after a full stop . '